# How to not wipe the whole disk, only the partition i want ubuntu on?

Tags: installation, partitioning, disk

I have in my old laptop, one harddisk which is split in two equal sized partitions.
Partition C got the windows xp boot and some odd files that i don't care much for since i always do a backup regularly of the C partition.

The other partition, D is seldom backupped, as I do know a new windows installation do not affect the D partition, it only wipe the C and reinstalls there.

My question is therefore:
When I see the screenshots of the Ubuntu installation process, I see the option to wipe the disk and install Ubuntu. Does that mean it wipes both of my partitions, or is there an expert option somewhere that allows me to wipe only the C partition, and keep the D partition untouched, and I would still have full access to my photos and other files there?

Thank you :)

Comment: There are both options. Could you post a link to the specific screenshot you mean, so we can explain it to you?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using advanced partitioning:

1. Choose Something Else at this menu.
2. Let it scan your partitions.(It does this automatically, and shows a spinner below the table while it is doing this)
3. Select your C: drive(It won't be called that, but something *like*(not exactly that) `/dev/sda1`, and it should be the second-to last partition)
4. Click Delete below. This will delete after this step so if you make a mistake it can be undone.
5. Click Add after selecting the empty space left over.
6. Set size to 4000.
7. Set the Use As field to Linux Swap.
8. Click OK.
9. Click on the free space remaining. Click Add below.
10. Create a new partition. Use As: Ext4, check the format box.
11. Click Edit on that partition. Set the mountpoint to `/`.
12. **You cannot undo after this step**. Click Install and continue as normal.

Comment: the screenshot is on fourth step here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: @janisi Pick the second option and follow my guide in this answer.

Comment: yes i just refreshed this page - thank you very much! :) :)

Comment: @janisi If this helped, consider marking this answer as accepted with the checkmark to the left so that future users know to use this one, and so that it is marked as answered in the lists.